# How to first compare two dates, then check to see if the number of days is less than or equal to 7

Tags: php

The first date is today's date and the second one is being retrieved from a DB. The purpose of what I'm trying to do is that I want to trigger an alert 7 days before the due date, which is the date stored in the DB.

I have tried to figure this out a few different ways without any success. I started by using the `strtotime` function to subtract days from the retrieved date and then compare it to today's date. Here is my first try:

```
$date1 =  strtotime(date('2013-11-14',strtotime('-7 days')));
$date2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$check = $date1 - $date2;
$check = date('j',$check);
if($check <= 7){echo "Under 1 week";}
```

But that doesn't work because it doesn't take into account the month, only the day...so 2013-12-14 will return the same result as 2013-11-13.

So then I tried:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$interval->format('%a');
if($interval <= 7){echo "Under 1 week";}
```

But then I get an error:

```
*Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int*
```

I figured that a number was an integer no matter what, but I've now learned that isn't the case.

I have done a lot of searching on the internet, because I'm sure someone else has been trying to do this same thing and I found this helpful bit of code that works perfectly:

```
function e_days($end,$start) {
/************************************************************************/
/* Purpose: To get the elapsed days of date diff as integer.            */
/************************************************************************/
$dtS = new DateTime($start);
$dtE = new DateTime($end);
$int = $dtE->diff($dtS);
$ret = (integer) $int->format('%a');
return $ret;
}  // end function
```

Normally I would just carry on and be happy, but I don't like to just use something I found without understanding it. The part I don't understand is this line:

```
$ret = (integer) $int->format('%a');
```

What is "(integer)" ? I assume it must change the number to an integer but I can't find it on php.net listed as a `function`.

I would also like to know if there is another way to do this, or if this guy nailed it.

Function Credit: [OldManRiver](http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?p=1168852&postcount=11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(integer)` casts whatever immediate follows it as an `int` type. In your case, it casts `$int->format('%a')` into an integer.

Consider the following (`int` is an alias for `integer`):

```
$str = "10";
$num = (int)$str;
 
if ($str === 10) echo "String";
if ($num === 10) echo "Integer";
```

In the example above, `$int = $dtE->diff($dtS)`, so `int` is the difference between two `DateTime` objects in *`DateTime` format*. According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php), `format('%a')` returns the total number of days between the two objects. Casting the return value using `(integer)` ensures that it will be an `int` type.

**UPDATE**:

More info on type-casting can be found [here (for integers)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) and [here (for general "type juggling")](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

From the docs:

> To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or (integer) casts.
>
> (int), (integer) - cast to integer

Comment: Do you have a link to the php.net site for (integer)?